# A <div> is created in JavaScript for dollar sign

Tags: javascript, c#

I have this Razor code:

```
<script>
    app.run(function () {
        var key = $('#@Model.HtmlId');
        key.inputFilter(function (value) {
            return new RegExp('@Html.Raw(RegularExpressions.KeyPattern)').test(value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is my `RegularExpressions` class:

```
public class RegularExpressions
{
    public const string KeyPattern = @"^[a-z-]+$";
    
    // other patterns
}
```

And what I get in my rendered HTML (page source in browser) is this:

```
<script>
    app.run(function () {
        var key = $('#key_Key_b13dca0421ac4740b5e177b80c002c25');
        key.inputFilter(function (value) {
            return new RegExp('^[a-z-]+$').test(value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, I get this JavaScript error in my browser console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

And when I click on it, I see this code:

```
    app.run(function () {
        var key = $('#key_Key_5be9a1756c8549199d3b37e0eea35bba');
        key.inputFilter(function (value) {
            return new RegExp('^[a-z-]+</div>).test(value);
        });
    });
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: `$'` is a special sequence, e.g. [in some regex contexts](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter), though I’m not quite sure _what_ produces this replacement. Make sure to escape it, e.g. `$$'`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, awesome. That solved it. Please send your comment as an answer so that I can accept it, for others to use.